# How can I create a termstore for individual site collection use only?

Tags: term-store

I am using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. After investigate Enterprise keyword feature I think it is quite close to what my users need. Since my farm have mulitple site collections, I want to limit the term created to be used within site collection only. Is it possible to configure?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create Site Collection specific Term Stores, but you can create Site Collection specific (local) Term Sets. Details [here](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/SP2010-Managed-Metadata-Global-vs-Local-Term-Sets).

Answer (score 1):

Use local term sets.

Local term sets are created within the context of a site collection. For example, if you add a column to a list in a document library, and create a new term set to bind the column to, the new term set is local to the site collection that contains the document library.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee424402(v=office.15).aspx